# The hangman game backward #6

Tags: riddle, knowledge, english, language, letters

Hangman game backward version 6 - guess what was the question:

fill in a "d" -  I am a magical device that you can convert energy with the tip of your fingers.
fill in a "g" - You can hear, under one condition, miles away from me.
fill in a "t" - It's been a long day, come to me and I'll make it short for you.

Again, your answer can be in the form of:

> The question was: _ p p l e

Comment: just to clarify, there won't be any extra d's, g's, n's, or t's in the word will there?

Comment: Ha Kingrames you got me there, I removed a row to make the missing letter unique.  I might add it back as a hint later

Comment: Formal protest (spoilers): Your "g" clue does not describe its [answer](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/winger?s=t). If instead, you were thinking of a band, you've broken a rule of hangman: No proper nouns!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> WIN_ER

fill in a "d" - I am a magical device that you can convert energy with the tip of your fingers.

> WINDER is not exactly magical, but it does allow you to convert work from the twisting of your fingers to potential/elastic energy.

fill in a "g" - You can hear, under one condition, miles away from me

> WINGER is a heavy metal band with one song called 'Under one Condition' and another called 'Miles Away'

fill in a "t" - It's been a long day, come to me and I'll make it short for you.

> WINTER days are shorter during winter season

And the edited clue
fill in a "n" - I believe you wished you were me!

> WINNER is something that people wish they were.

Comment: You're so close!  I will accept your answer once you figure out the missing piece

Comment: @Alex how about now

Comment: I see you find the missing piece, just a note, *Under one condition* is also a song from them.  Well done!

Comment: @Alex I was going too quickly and looked right over it. Thanks for the notice and fun puzzle!

Comment: Welcome!  I wonder how you get the first 2 answer thou, was it too obvious?

Comment: Not obvious to me!

Comment: Not obvious, just used the information you conveyed. Knowing that there was an extra N helped narrow it down. My favorite clue, and the one that gave me confidence in this set was the T clue. In my opinion that was your best one

Comment: dang, I knew it!  I was hesitated to include the "n" line =D

Comment: Nor to me. I thought Winter would work for the last one, but dismissed it because I didn't think Winger or Winder were things...might have forged ahead if I had noticed the Winner clue. Also, doesn't hangman forbid proper nouns? Perhaps the winger is a very loud rugby player.

Comment: I thought of winger in general for sport too, but it's sort of hard to hide it when the hint is related to sport.  As of no Nouns, I will keep in mind for my next one~